# From $(1)$ and $(2)$, t $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence equivalent to a uniformly integrable sequence.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and 
$$
\mathcal{L}^1=\left\{f:E\to \mathbb{R}: \int_{E}{|f(t)|d\mu(t)}<\infty\right\}
$$
Let $\{f_n\}\subset \mathcal{L}^1$, such that:
$$
\sup_{n}{\int_{E}{|f_n(t)|d\mu(t)}}<\infty
$$
Such that, there exists a subsequence $\{g_{m}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$, such that for all subsequence $\{g_{m_i}\}$ of $\{g_m\}$
$$
\{g_{m_i}1_{|g_{m_i}|\leq i})\}\text{ is uniformly integrable,} \qquad (1)
$$
$$
\sum_{i\geq 1}{\mu\big(\{t\in E~:~|g_{m_i}(t)|>i \}\big)}<+\infty,\qquad (2)
$$

Why : **"From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see the known result that $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence equivalent
to a uniformly integrable sequence. "**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\{f_n\}$ is a subsequence that is uniformly integrable. Otherwise, 
$$\infty >\sup_n \int_E |f_n| \, d\mu >0,$$ in which case I claim that the subsequence $\{g_m\}_{m=N}^\infty$ of $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable for large enough $N$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $A\in \cal{A}$. Put 
$$A_i = \{x \in E: |g_{i}(x)|> i\}.$$

From (2), $\mu(A_i) \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $i \geq N$ implies 
$$\mu(A_i) < \frac{\epsilon}{2\sup_n \int_E |f_n| \, d \mu}.$$

From (1), choose $\delta >0$ such that $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu(A) < \delta$ implies 
$$
\int_A |g_i| \cdot 1_{E\setminus A_i}\, d\mu  < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$

Then $i \geq N$ and $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies

\begin{align*}
\int_A |g_i| \, d\mu & = \int_{A\cap A_i} |g_i| \, d\mu + \int_{A\cap (E\setminus A_i)} |g_i| \, d\mu\\
& = \int_{E} |g_i|\cdot 1_{A\cap A_i} \, d\mu + \int_{E} |g_i| \cdot 1_{A\cap (E\setminus A_i)}\, d\mu\\
& \leq \mu(A_i) \cdot \sup_n |f_n| \, d\mu  +\int_E|g_i| \cdot 1_{E\setminus A_i}\, d\mu\\
& < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
 = \epsilon. 
\end{align*}

This proves that the subsequence $\{g_m\}_{m=N}^\infty$ of $\{f_n\}$
is uniformly integrable.

Comment: If $\{g_m\}_{m\geq N}$ is uniformly integrable then $\{g_m\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: Agreed but we need only show existence of a subsequence to answer the posters question.

Comment: $\int_{E}{|g_i| 1_{A\cap A_i}d\mu}\leq \mu(A_i)\sup_n\int_{E}{|f_n|d\mu}$?